# В выпадающем списке городов надо сделать **currentCity** цвет color: greenyellow , но синтаксис [class.name]="expression" не сработал

Tags: javascript, angular, scss

В html модуле прописал это:

```
<a              class="navigation__dropdown-menu-item"
                *ngFor="let city of cities"
                (click)="setCurrentCity(city); cityDropdown = false"
                [class.active]="city.id === currentCity" //эта строчка не работает
              >
                {{ city.name }}
              </a>
```

В scss модуле добавлено это

```
.navigation__dropdown-menu-item {
&.active {color: greenyellow;}
&:hover {color: $primary-color;} 
}
```

Должно всё работать, не понимаю что же не так?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел свою ошибку:

```
[class.active]="city.id === currentCity.id"
```

вот так должна выглядеть строчка, чтобы expression был true.